# In MySQL version 8.19, I am getting - error 1525; Incorrect Date Value: ''

Tags: mysql

, when running this query getting Error1525

```
SELECT customer_no 
FROM sales_flat_order
WHERE transaction_id='237'
 AND kwi_store_id='265036'
 AND register='22'
 AND day_date = ''
```

I have set sql_mode = '' and restarted the mysqld service.  This doesn't work.  Is there no way to fix this new feature introduced in 8.16, where you can't query for no value in a date field?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It shouldn't be possible to have no value in there... or do you mean `NULL`?

Comment: Can we see the structure of the table?

Comment: In java you pass a ? for variable, sometimes the varible is empty '', Mysql used to allow this, since 8.16 it does not.    The day_date field is what is causing the issue and its structure is just a date field that allows null, no boxes checked, utf8 charset

Comment: `NULL` isn't the same as an empty string `''`. `day_date` must be a nullable date field to contain null. The` .0` in the mysql version is significant. So `8.0.19` is the version.

Comment: There are no blank values in the day_date column, there are null values and populated values 'YYYY-MM-DD'.  You should still be able to query for nothing, by removing the "strict " configuration that was added in 8.0.16.  It may not be with current version, and might be permanent.  You can replicate this by querying for '' in  a date column

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE ..  day_date IS NULL`

Comment: I'll never pass a null in the day_date parameter, it will either be 'YYYY-MM-DD' or '', the '' is causing the issue, I'd rather fix this on the database side than alter the middleware production deployment

Comment: Also tried setting sql_mode = 'ALLOW_INVALID_DATES', also not working

Comment: `AND day_date = ''` will in your case never return any rows. If your data is `null`, it won't be true (as `null` isn't the same as `''`), and if your data is a valid date, it will also not be true. It will also not find the invalid `0000-00-00` dates. (So this error basically prevents you from doing something that wouldn't work anyway.) So you may want to redesign your query generation, e.g. don't add empty parameters if they are, as I suppose, not to be meant as a search parameter (e.g. if `''` should mean "anything, any date or null or whatever" instead of "is null/actually not given").

Answer (score 0):

Just went with varchar(10) for the field in question, instead of date data type.  Needed a database solution.